# Unity is not working after installing nvidia-313 drivers

Tags: unity, drivers, nvidia, 13.04

Neither the window manager, I just installed Ubuntu 13.04 in a Hp Pavilion dv2000, the installation was fine except for some annoying graphic glitches, so I decide to install the nvidia Drivers from xorg-edgers/319, when I rebooted the laptop, Unity was gone.
I tried by installiin th elinux.generic-headers, installing th 173 and current package instead of the 319 from xorg-edgers, but nothing.
Any thoughts on how to fix it?

Comment: I would suggest giving the [mainline kernel](https://github.com/GM-Script-Writer-62850/Ubuntu-Mainline-Kernel-Updater#readme) a try, the stock `3.8.0-19-generic` kernel has been known to act up with nvidia

Comment: Have you selected the latest driver from the `Additional Drivers` list?

Comment: You might want to read this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia

Comment: @JesusLives ii Which Graphics card do you use?

Comment: @GM-Script-Writer-62850 I already tried that kernel.

Comment: @thefourtheye There is only one additional driver in that list, the one of broadcom, and I asume that the laptop is equipped with a Nvidia 150 Go.

Comment: Have you tried, `sudo apt-get install nvidia-313-updates`

Comment: if [this](http://www.specsbox.com/590/hp-pavilion-dv2000-notebook-specs.html) is your laptop you have a intel gpu, not a nvidia gpu, you dont use a nvidia gpu on a intel gpu, you use a intel gpu, there is a note in the xorg edgers ppa details for you